# Prove $1-cos(2\pi k/n)=2sin(kπ/n)sin((n−k)\pi/n)$

Tags: trigonometry

It looks like a sum to product question, however, I couldn't find a way to make it work.

Prove 
$$1-cos\frac{2\pi k}{n}=2sin\frac{k\pi }{n}sin\frac{(n−k)\pi }{n}$$

Comment: See also: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/WernerFormulas.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just note that $\cos 2x = 1-2\sin^2x$ and $\sin x=\sin (\pi-x)$.